# How do you do a theme change animation in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Steps to see what I mean:

1. Head to [the vuetify website](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/)
2. Click on the cog icon
3. Select either dark or light theme.

As you alternate between different themes, an animation plays. A circle (starting from roughly the position of the button) expands, eventually engulfing the entire screen in the new theme.

I can't find any instructions in the docs on how that can be replicated. For me, a transition plays where the colours fade into their new variants, but it looks quite tacky compared to what they have going on.

Is this a feature of vuetify? How can I replicate this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one on vuetifyjs.com works by copying the entire DOM, setting the correct scroll positions on the copied elements, then applying a css clip-path transition to reveal the original DOM with the new theme applied.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/60218ee82cabaf0d6c1f22d64a24c0e32b4e4247/packages/docs/src/App.vue#L96

```js
watch(theme.global.name, themeTransition)

function themeTransition () {
  const x = performance.now()
  for (let i = 0; i++ < 1e7; i << 9 & 9 % 9 * 9 + 9);
  if (performance.now() - x > 10) return

  const el = document.querySelector('[data-v-app]')
  const children = el.querySelectorAll('*')

  children.forEach(el => {
    if (hasScrollbar(el)) {
      el.dataset.scrollX = String(el.scrollLeft)
      el.dataset.scrollY = String(el.scrollTop)
    }
  })

  const copy = el.cloneNode(true)
  copy.classList.add('app-copy')
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
  copy.style.top = rect.top + 'px'
  copy.style.left = rect.left + 'px'
  copy.style.width = rect.width + 'px'
  copy.style.height = rect.height + 'px'

  const targetEl = document.activeElement
  const targetRect = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect()
  const left = targetRect.left + targetRect.width / 2 + window.scrollX
  const top = targetRect.top + targetRect.height / 2 + window.scrollY
  el.style.setProperty('--clip-pos', `${left}px ${top}px`)
  el.style.removeProperty('--clip-size')

  nextTick(() => {
    el.classList.add('app-transition')
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        el.style.setProperty('--clip-size', Math.hypot(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) + 'px')
      })
    })
  })

  document.body.append(copy)

  copy.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll-x], [data-scroll-y]').forEach(el => {
    el.scrollLeft = +el.dataset.scrollX
    el.scrollTop = +el.dataset.scrollY
  })

  function onTransitionend (e) {
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
      copy.remove()
      el.removeEventListener('transitionend', onTransitionend)
      el.removeEventListener('transitioncancel', onTransitionend)
      el.classList.remove('app-transition')
      el.style.removeProperty('--clip-size')
      el.style.removeProperty('--clip-pos')
    }
  }
  el.addEventListener('transitionend', onTransitionend)
  el.addEventListener('transitioncancel', onTransitionend)
}

function hasScrollbar (el) {
  if (!el || el.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) return false

  const style = window.getComputedStyle(el)
  return style.overflowY === 'scroll' || (style.overflowY === 'auto' && el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight)
}
```

```
.app-copy
  position: fixed !important
  z-index: -1 !important
  pointer-events: none !important
  contain: size style !important
  overflow: clip !important

.app-transition
  --clip-size: 0
  --clip-pos: 0 0
  clip-path: circle(var(--clip-size) at var(--clip-pos))
  transition: clip-path .35s ease-out
```

Comment: Terrifying... and probably only going to work on mostly static pages right? Wouldn't this kill off js pretty badly?

Comment: Never mind, reading through this I now see that it's the copy that gets deleted, rather than the original (which makes way more sense)

Comment: i got it working :D Thanks for that. The main thing I did have to change was the watch had to look at a different computed, as the theme is applied via my own code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to achieve this:

```
<template>
  <v-app :dark="darkTheme">
    <v-btn @click="toggleTheme">Change Theme</v-btn>
    <v-main>
      <transition name="circle-expand">
        <div :class="themeClass" v-if="isThemeVisible">
          <!-- Your application content here -->
        </div>
      </transition>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      darkTheme: false,
      isThemeVisible: true
    };
  },
  computed: {
    themeClass() {
      return {
        'theme--light': !this.darkTheme,
        'theme--dark': this.darkTheme
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTheme() {
      this.isThemeVisible = false; // Hide the content during transition
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.darkTheme = !this.darkTheme; // Toggle theme
        this.isThemeVisible = true; // Show the content after theme change
      }, 500); // Adjust the delay to match the transition duration
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.circle-expand-enter-active,
.circle-expand-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.circle-expand-enter,
.circle-expand-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.circle-expand-enter {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.circle-expand-leave-to {
  transform: scale(2);
}
</style>
```

Clicking the button will toggle the `darkTheme` boolean, which applies the dark or light theme to the entire `Vuetify` application. The transition animation remains the same, smoothly transitioning the theme change with the expanding circle effect. Adjust the transition duration and timing functions as needed.

Comment: This looks like it might work for simple pages, but containing the entire application within a v-if means that all of the components will be reset... so this solution won't work for me.